# Adding external file for use in MapReduce driver Class

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, distributed-cache

I am trying to add a text file: sample.txt to be used in my MapReduce program within the Driver class. I have tried adding the file using

```
-files sample.txt
```

within my yarn jar command. This is adding it to the distributed cache, but I can only access the file in my mapper and reducer classes. I need to access it in my Driver class.

I have also tried to directly reference the file using a path but that also does not seem to work. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Where are you executing your job on? And you should be able to reference the file from your code using complete path to that file. Do you get any error message ?

Comment: Maybe its the path I am using. Would it be relative to where the jar of my mapreduce is located or the script that I am using to run the jar?

Comment: @Amar Ahh you were right, I was thinking the path was relative to the jar but it was relative to the workspace directory. It works now that I updated the complete path to the file. Thanks!